# confusion receiving an string value with functions list() and split()

Tags: php

```
buy.php

<form action="cart.php">
<input style="width:10px; margin-left:9px; " name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="'  .    $variety['price']. '_'. $variety['variety'] '_'. $product['name']. '"  />
 </form>
```

I am sending the input form above to cart.php inthere I receive it like:

```
list($aDoor, $variety,$productname) = split('_', $_POST['price']);
$aDoor = array();
$variety = array();
$productname= // $productname is a string how can I set it up here?

foreach ($_POST['price'] as $p)
{
  list($a, $b,$c) = explode('_', $p);
  $aDoor[] = $a;
  $variety[] = $b;
  $productname =$c; // and I have put it equal to the variable $c here
}
```

The only problem above is receiving the index $product['name'] coming from the form in buy.php

In cart.php I have set it  up to be received by $productname but as you can see this is an string not a array how can I set it up when it is an string in with the functions list() and split() it confuses me.

Comment: You should accept answers to your previous questions if the y helped you.

Comment: felix I did accept them but it is hard to post in through post code through the comments tab, so I save time by posting but I do use all the other post answers thank you.

Comment: No offense, but you did not accept them. With "accept" I mean to mark one answer with the green tick. And for code in comments: You can always edit your question to provide additional code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. There's a few things wrong with your script.

1) You've not specified a method on your form tag, so by default the data will be submitted as a 'GET'. You're using $_POST in your script, so those values will be blank and the foreach loop will fail as $_POST['price'] doesn't exist.

2) You're naming the checkbox as "price[]". The [] tells PHP that there will be multiple values submitted with this same name, so that $_GET['price'] will be an array. Your first few lines of code will then fail, as split works on strings, not arrays. You'll end up with the following values assigned

```
 $aDoor = "Array"
 $variety = NULL;
 $productname = NULL;
```

PHP attempts to convert your $*GET['price'] array to a string, but this defaults to just coming back as the string 'Array', and there's no "*" values in there, so the rest of the list() variables having nothing to be assigned to them, so they become null.

3) Split's been deprecated and will be removed in PHP 6, so use explode() instead (as you do just a few lines later)

4) You then immediately trash those values by assigning empty arrays for $aDoor and $variety, so in effect the split line was useless

The foreach loop looks fine, though you'll want to assign to a $productname array, instead of a string, so use $productname[] = $c;

5) I would, however, not store the data you're explode()ing in three seperate arrays. It would make more sense to
store it like this:

```
$products = array();
foreach($_POST['price'] as $p) {
   list($a, $b, $c) = explode('_', $p);
   $products[] = array('aDoor' => $a, 'variety' => $b, 'productname' => $c);
}
```

This way you don't have to pass around 3 arrays (or make them 'global') in any functions that use this data, you can pass just a single variable (ie: updateInventory($products[7]); )

5) If this shopping cart script was released into the wild, it could be a gaping security hole on the server. What would stop someone from constructing their own price by passing in something like "$0.00_fire engine red-ferrari" as the price field? I've always wanted a free Ferrari, and round-tripping pricing data through the user's browser is a nice way to get it. Never, ever, trust a client to NOT hack up critical data, such as its price.

Comment: I have var_dump($productname); to see why it is not displaying in the browser right after foreach ($_POST['price'] as $p)
{
  list($a,$b,$c) = explode('_', $p);
  $aDoor[] = $a;
  $variety[] = $b;
  $productname[] = $c;
}

var_dump($productname);

And it display as:

array(0) { }  and it is passing empty.

help.

Comment: Try var_dump()ing your $_POST array and see exactly what's being passed into yoru script. If the $productname array is coming out empty at the end, I'd suspect your HTML form isn't being constructed properly. Try viewing the page source (View -> Source, or whatever) in the browser and look at the <input> tags, see if they're being built properly in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the `method` attribute of the `form`, the default is `GET`. In your script you are using `POST`, try putting `POST` method to your form:

```
 <form action="cart.php" method="post">
```

Secondly, even if `$productname` is a string but you can convert it to array (like you have done for other vars) by suffixing it with `[]`, so your code becomes:

```
$aDoor = array();
$variety = array();
$productname = array();

foreach ($_POST['price'] as $p)
{
  list($a,$b,$c) = explode('_', $p);
  $aDoor[] = $a;
  $variety[] = $b;
  $productname[] = $c;
}
```

Now these three arrays contains your data.

Comment: I have done the above, pluse the code below and it is not working.

else 
{
   $P = count($productname);
for($i=0; $i < $P; $i++)
    {
   echo'<div class="product">'; echo $productname[$i]; echo'</div>'; 
}

Comment: I have var_dump($productname); to see why it is not displaying in the browser right after foreach ($_POST['price'] as $p)
{
  list($a,$b,$c) = explode('_', $p);
  $aDoor[] = $a;
  $variety[] = $b;
  $productname[] = $c;
}

var_dump($productname);

And it display as:

array(0) { }  and it is passing empty.

help.

Comment: @Jona: ok then it is great news :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$productname = '';
```

Comment: And How could I display it Jansen?